# Modifying data sent by a 3rd party JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a client's website which uses a 3rd party library to populate a `dropdown` the code in the SELECT is:

```
 <select border="0"  class="" id="country" style="" name="country"  size="1" onchange="ChangeCountryAndStateLabel(
                      {
                         'obj'       : this,
                         'targetObj' : '#state_cus1',
                         'sel'       : '',
                         'id'        : 'fields_state'
                      }
                      , 
                      {
                         'obj'       : this,
                         'targetObj' : '#fields_state_region',
                         'template'  : '<LABEL>:'
                      });" >
                <option value="" onclick="" >Select Country</option>
                <option value="38" onclick="" >Canada</option>
                <option value="223" onclick="" >United States</option></select>
```

That will populate:

```
<div id="state_cus1" style="width:165px;">
                <input type="text" id="fields_state" name="fields_state" value="" onchange="SetStateHid(this);"/>
            </div>
```

With all the states (if i would chose United States).

I would like to then REMOVE entries bassed on the value.

The output of selecting US would be like this:

```
<div id="state_cus1" style="width:165px;">
                <input type="text" id="fields_state" name="fields_state" value="" onchange="SetStateHid(this);"/>
            </div>
<option value="AL" onclick="">Alabama (AL)</option>
etc etc etc...
```

Once this has been populated, I would like to remove a few based on Value.

So To remove Florida I tried:

```
$("select > option[value*='FL']").remove();
```

However due to the fact that JS runs in order and does not wait, this will not work as it is run before the `select` is ever populated.

How would I go about only running that function AFTER the `select` has been populated?

**EDIT**

Also Tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#fields_state").on("change", function(){
    $("#fields_state > option[value*='FL']").remove();
}
```

**EDIT 2**

`OnChange` has been removed, and the code has been moved to `.ready()`

```
   ll(document).ready(function() {
      ll("#country").change(function(){
        ChangeCountryAndStateLabel({
           'obj'       : this,
           'targetObj' : '#state_cus1',
           'sel'       : '',
           'id'        : 'fields_state'
        },{
           'obj'       : this,
           'targetObj' : '#fields_state_region',
           'template'  : '<LABEL>'
        });

        ll("#fields_state > option[value*='FL']").remove();
    });
```

This method still fills the `select` full of options, but does not remove the FL entry.

Comment: add the code in the last box to just between the semi and quote (; X ") in the onchange attrib of the first box's code. don't forget to toothpick your inner quotes.

Comment: like this: `});$("#fields_state > option[value*='FL']").remove();" >` ?

Comment: yeah, but without busted quotes: '#fields_state > option[value*=\'FL\']'

Comment: @dandavis using `$('#fields_state > option[value*=\'FL\']').remove();" >` does not remove FL from the option list. Maybe I have it in the wrong place?

Comment: There are more appropriate solutions. You should keep your Javascript separate from your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Place this:

```
$("select > option[value*='FL']").remove();
```

Inside this:

```
$("#country").on("change", function(){
    $("#fields_state > option[value*='FL']").remove();
}
```

That'll only remove when the select is changed. Put that in your JS and you'll be golden.

**EDIT**

The best solution would be to remove the `onchange` all together. Then place the code in your JS, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#country").on("change", function(){
        ChangeCountryAndStateLabel({
           'obj'       : this,
           'targetObj' : '#state_cus1',
           'sel'       : '',
           'id'        : 'fields_state'
        },{
           'obj'       : this,
           'targetObj' : '#fields_state_region',
           'template'  : '<LABEL>'
        });

        $("#fields_state > option[value*='FL']").remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: That was a no go, Added under `.ready()` but does not remove the option after the change. If it helps the select ID is fields_state. See edit for what I have changed.

Comment: Removing the `OnChange()` and using your code in the `.ready()` does not work, I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } `

Comment: The error you're getting is because I missed a `}` at one point. I've edited my answer to correct that. It should work just fine now.

Comment: I still get an error with this code, Still the same `}` error. However with the code in edit 2 it does function just does not remove the FL value.

Comment: Why do you have `ll` instead of `$`? Here: `ll(document).ready()`

Comment: Could you make a fiddle? That would make this a lot easier to fix.